# Correlated features and Trees

Tags: correlation, random-forest

I'm using random forest to predict a binary classification target, that I obtain putting a threshold on a continuos feature. Before fitting the classifier I compute the correlation matrix with the sklearn $corr()$ function, among all my data including the target both continuos and binarized. Intuitively, I do this since I want to see which feature are more correlated with my target, and I guess that I should really look at the correlation with the target BEFORE binarizing, to not lose information.

Anyway, I expect that the more a feature is correlated with my target (binarized or not), the more it will be relevant after fitting the classifier. Contrary to my intuition, running random forest in sklearn and asking for the attribute feature_importances_ I usually find that the more correlated feature are not the most important ones. Why it is so?

Comment: The feature importance can be different from classification task to another classification task. In your case, you compute feature correlations w/o considering the classification task and try to compare that by feature importances returned by a trained random forest classifier. These things can be not only on a different scale but also mean different things.